# Signature delegation without secret keys

Tags: public-key, signature, zero-knowledge-proofs, proxy-re-encryption

Scenario: have an entity A that cannot hold any secret keys. A concrete example would be: an application that needs to be open sourced and cannot be modified. In order to send any signed messages, it uses a proxy signer P. P holds the secret key and signs on behalf of A.

The issue: how does the message recipient verify that A actually initiated the message via P, and P did not generate/send the message without A's knowledge?

I came across some papers that discuss proxy signer's deviation, but could not find anything concrete. Could zk proofs be used in some ways to address this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: In order for your question to be answered completely I think you have to define first your communication and thread model.

Some questions that will help you complete your question :

Let's consider $C$ the client, $A$ the application and $S$ the signer (which is $P$ in your case).

Comment: 1. Does $S$ have a direct communication channel with $C$ or it just replies to $A$ with the signed message and $A$ forwards it to $C$?
2. Is the party $S$ trusted?
3. Are there any preestablished (bidirectional?) secure communication channels, if yes which of the following $\{A,S\}$, $\{A, C\}$, $\{C, P\}$?
4. Does $S$ have whitebox access to $A$? Will a corrupted $S$ will have full control of both $A$ and $S$?

If the last question is true, of course this problem cannot be solved.

Comment: 1. S can be thought of as mail box between A and C. A <-> C don't talk to each other directly, but only via S
2. S can be trusted, but from point of view of C, we still want to make sure it is not creating/signing messages on its own. This can be thought of as a selling point for this scheme, where C can somehow verify the message originated from A
3. No pre-created channels
4. S does not have any control over A and C

Comment: How do you distinguish A from A' (the identical application running on the adversary's machine, or possibly a tweaked version of the application)?  Unless you have a way to do that, I don't believe this is possible...

Comment: Totally agree with @poncho.

Comment: Given the constraint that A cannot hold any secrets, keeping anything like a TLS key/cert, etc is not feasible. I can't think of a way to distinguish between  A and A' to be honest.